# MongoDB $subtract in $redact throwing 'object is already an operator expression' Error

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am having a weird error when I try run an aggreate query with subtract.

With the query below:

```
$ops = array(

        array(
            '$redact' => array(
                '$cond' => array(
                    'if' => array( 
                        '$gte' => array('$subtract' => array(20 ,10), 10)
                    ),
                    'then' => '$$KEEP',
                    'else' => '$$PRUNE'
                )
            )
        )
    );

$results = $collection ->aggregate($ops);
```

Logically, this should subtract 20 - 10, and the compare if result is greater or equal to 10. The problem is it throws this error:

> MongoResultException: localhost:27017: this object is already an
>   operator expression, and can't be used as a document expression (at
>   '0')

Now when I remove the $subtract and I run this:

```
$ops = array(
                array(
                    '$redact' => array(
                        '$cond' => array(
                            'if' => array( 
                                '$gte' => array(10,10)
                            ),
                            'then' => '$$KEEP',
                            'else' => '$$PRUNE'
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
```

This compare if 10 is greater than 10, which works without the error. So why is the $subtract causing the above error message?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the $subtract must be wrapped in array.

```
'$gte' => array(array('$subtract' => array(20 ,10)), 10)
```